# React - Handling and validating a dynamic number of inputs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object, input

**Background:** I am relatively new to React, and I am attempting to create a React flashcard site to add to my portfolio. I want to create an app that will create "flashcards" for each letter in the selected Japanese alphabet. Hiragana contains about 107 letters/combo letters and Katakana contains about the same. The alphabets share many of the same letters, but they are visually written differently. i.e. Hir: a = あ; Kat: a = ア. This means each alphabet has to be uniquely identifiable when attempting to validate any given input's data.

**Problem:** How to dynamically create all flashcards without manually creating a state for each.

**Json data:** [jCharacters.json](https://github.com/justin-barfield/japanese-flashcards/blob/main/client/src/jCharacters.json)

**Card creation code:**

```
<div className="row">
    {Object.keys(this.state.jCharacters.hiragana.hir).map( (key, index) => (
        <div className="card text-center" key= {index}>
            <div>
                <h5 className="card-title" >{this.state.jCharacters.hiragana.hir[key].character}</h5>
                <input type="text" name={this.state.jCharacters.hiragana.hir[key].characterName} value={this.state.input[index]} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
            </div>
        </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

**handleChange:** Current code adds a new state with the characterName for each input. This is flawed.

```
Change(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
};
```

Any input is appreciated to get past this roadblock.

Answer (score 0):

create an extra component (e.g. "Flashcard"), which has own state. Then render this components in the map:

```
const Flashcard = React.FC = ({character, name}) => {
    const [answer, updateAnswer] = React.useState("")
    React.useEffect(()=>{
        ...handleChange...
    },[answer])
    return <div>
            <h5 className="card-title" >{character}</h5>
            <input type="text" name={name} value={answer} onChange={(e) => updateAnswer(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
}

...

//in the main component:
<div className="row">
    {this.state.jCharacters.hiragana.hir.map((item, index) => (
        <div className="card text-center" key={index}>
            <Flashcard character={item.character} name={item.characterName} />
        </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

Comment: This is using Hooks correct? If I wanted to run validation on the inputs I would need to have it within the Component correct?

Comment: Yes, you can create a validation method in the component, or you can pass a custom validation function as a property.